# Asterisk 11.7 Matching on Caller ID

Tags: asterisk

I've an asterisk pbx that manages some sip providers (a ISDN Patton) and some Voip providers.
I'm trying to use matching of CID in my dialplan as described [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Pattern+Matching).
This is the relevant part of my dialplan, please note that this part of dialplan is included my extension.conf:

```
[patton];Calls from Patton
exten => 0219999999/_0031X.,1,Answer(0)  
exten => 0219999999/_0031X.,n,Hangout()

exten => 0219999999,1,Answer(0)   
exten => 0219999999,n,Goto(in_4,${EXTEN},1)

[in_4]
exten => 0219999999,1,Noop(Exten: ${EXTEN})
exten => 0219999999,n,Noop(CID: ${CALLERID(NUM)})
```

In short I want do something different when the CID of the caller cames from Netherlands.
Watching what happens in Asterisk CLI I see:

```
 == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
-- Executing [0219999999@patton:1] Answer("SIP/patton-00000011", "0") in new stack
-- Executing [0219999999@patton:2] Goto("SIP/patton-00000011", "in_4,0219999999,1") in new stack
-- Goto (in_4,0219999999,1)
-- Executing [0219999999@in_4:1] NoOp("SIP/patton-00000011", "Exten: 0219999999") in new stack
-- Executing [0219999999@in_4:2] NoOp("SIP/patton-00000011", "Cid: 0031123456789") in new stack
```

So what I understand is that Asterisk don't apply the CID matching but I don't understand why, considering that if I print the CID it matches perfectly my expression.

Comment: Is this for inbound or outbound calls?

Comment: Ahh ok. Inbound based on the fact the call comes from +31. I'll post an answer with my working inbound CID matching which actually catches calls from a few places.

Comment: Your dialplan and console output do not match (e.g. "Cid" instead of "CID" in NoOp call). Can you copy and paste your current dialplan with errors corrected (e.g. Hangout), then do `dialplan reload` and `core set debug 2`, THEN copy and paste output from a call as well as `core show dialplan patton`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a section of my extensions.conf file that deals with inbound caller ID matching (from a PSTN line)

There might be another/better way to do this, but its been a working config for me since 1.4 and I'm now running 13.7 without any issues. (Individual numbers have been replaced with '#') - This is a simple dial plan.

This is used to catch anyone who send an 084 or 087 prefix, a couple of specific numbers and anything from 'international' or lazy system administrators 'UNAVAILABLE'

I've the same thing set up for SIP trunks as well so this should work across any channel type.

```
[from-pstn]
exten => s,1,Verbose(CLID From BT ${CALLERID(all)})
exten => s,2,GotoIf($[${CALLERID(num):0:3} = 087]?103:3)
exten => s,3,GotoIf($[${CALLERID(num):0:3} = 084]?103:4)
exten => s,4,GotoIf($[${CALLERID(num):0:11} = 07896######]?103:5)
exten => s,5,GotoIf($[${CALLERID(num):0:11} = 01494######]?103:6)
exten => s,6,GotoIf($["${CALLERID(name):0:13}" = "INTERNATIONAL"]?103:7)
exten => s,7,GotoIf($["${CALLERID(name):0:11}" = "UNAVAILABLE"]?103:8)
exten => s,8,GotoIf($[${CALLERID(num):0:10} = 020315####]?103:9)
exten => s,103,Answer
exten => s,104,Wait(1)
exten => s,105,Playtones(info)
exten => s,106,Wait(7)
exten => s,107,Hangup
exten => s,9,Goto(internal-ext,5800,1)
```

You would want something like;

```
[from-yourtrunk]
exten => s,1,Verbose(CLID From <yourtrunk> ${CALLERID(all)})
exten => s,2,GotoIf($[${CALLERID(num):0:4} = 0031]?103:3)
exten => s,103,<do something with the call that matches the CLI>
exten => s,3,Goto(<your-internal-ext>,<number>,1)
```

Something to keep in mind - if you handle inbound caller ID that *could* start 0031 but its not a call from .nl then you would need to apply some additional patten matching to the 2nd line to enforce a minimum number of digits (for example) otherwise that will match *any* call that comes in with a CLI of 0031...............................

If you need any more explanation, or I've got the wrong end of the stick just add a comment to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There can be non zero probability, that cid is go in other format(use Verbose or Noop command to show real cid)

Also in this case any dialplan can work if cid match

Asterisk not select "most matching" dialplan. Insead it select FIRST matching dialplan.

You can use different contexts and include directive to control matching. See examples in extensions.conf.sample

```
    -- Executing [19@test:1] Answer("SIP/test2-0000821a", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [19@test:2] Set("SIP/test2-0000821a", "CALLERID(num)=0031123456789") in new stack
    -- Executing [19@test:3] Goto("SIP/test2-0000821a", "patton,0219999999,1") in new stack
    -- Goto (patton,0219999999,1)
    -- Executing [0219999999@patton:1] Answer("SIP/test2-0000821a", "0") in new stack
[Feb 10 08:26:09] WARNING[15817][C-00008bfe]: pbx.c:4869 pbx_extension_helper: No application 'Hangout' for extension (patton, 0219999999, 2)
  == Spawn extension (patton, 0219999999, 2) exited non-zero on 'SIP/test2-0000821a'
[Feb 10 08:26:45] NOTICE[1499]: chan_sip.c:28210 handle_request_register: Registration from '"407" <sip:407@78.47.159.180:5060>' failed for '221.144.172.3:5083' - Wrong password
pro-sip*CLI> dialplan show pa
park-dial            park-hints           park-orphan-routing  park-return-routing  parkedcalls          parkedcallstimeout   
patton               
pro-sip*CLI> dialplan show patton 
[ Context 'patton' created by 'pbx_config' ]
  '0219999999' (CID match '_0031X.') =>  1. Answer(0)                                  [pbx_config]
                    2. Hangout()                                  [pbx_config]
  '0219999999' =>   1. Answer(0)                                  [pbx_config]
                    2. Goto(in_4,${EXTEN},1)                      

[pbx_config] pro-sip*CLI> core show applications like  Hang
    -= Matching Asterisk Applications =-
         ChangeMonitor: Change monitoring filename of a channel. 
                Hangup: Hang up the calling channel. 
      HangupCauseClear: Clears hangup cause information from the channel that is available through HANGUPCAUSE. 
            SoftHangup: Hangs up the requested channel. 
    -= 4 Applications Matching =- pro-sip*CLI>
```

Addon2(please note, debug is OFFTOPIC on SO)

```
    -- Executing [0219999999@patton:1] NoOp("SIP/test2-0000821c", "cid match") in new stack
    -- Executing [0219999999@patton:2] Answer("SIP/test2-0000821c", "0") in new stack
[Feb 10 08:32:18] WARNING[15826][C-00008c00]: pbx.c:4869 pbx_extension_helper: No application 'Hangout' for extension (patton, 0219999999, 3)
  == Spawn extension (patton, 0219999999, 3) exited non-zero on 'SIP/test2-0000821c'
pro-sip*CLI> dialplan show pa
park-dial            park-hints           park-orphan-routing  park-return-routing  parkedcalls          parkedcallstimeout   
patton               
pro-sip*CLI> dialplan show patton 
[ Context 'patton' created by 'pbx_config' ]
  '0219999999' (CID match '_0031X.') =>  1. Noop(cid match)                            [pbx_config]
                    2. Answer(0)                                  [pbx_config]
                    3. Hangout()                                  [pbx_config]
  '0219999999' =>   1. NOOP(CIDNOTMATCH)                          [pbx_config]
                    2. Answer(0)                                  [pbx_config]
                    3. Goto(in_4,${EXTEN},1)                      [pbx_config]
```

Comment: As you can see I yet print the exact cid with Noop function; infact the cid arrived match exacty my pattern. FInally, Asterisk select the most specific pattern when it analizes dialplan, not the first matching. See here https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Pattern+Matching

Comment: ok, but anyway will be matched "first" record in memory for cid matching, you can do nothing here. So any one random dialplan. Use includes to control matching.

Comment: The context selected from Asterisk is correct, it enters in [patton] context, the wrong thing is that is not selected the extension 0219999999/_0031X. but instead is selected the 0219999999.

Comment: Okay, in your case it say "No application Hangout"(for some reason you removed that from output.

Comment: Is not that the point, yet at first line (Executing [0219999999@patton:1] Answer()) it's wrong. It should go to the extension with cid matching.

Comment: It GO  in this exactly case. Please check output. You SHOULD use Noop as first command to ensure it go.

Comment: I yet tried to set as first line NoOp and I'm absolutely certain that Asterisk pick up wrong extension.

Comment: As you can see from trace i do on test asterisk(asterisk 11) it select correct macth via cid. On asterisk 1.4(and maybe on 1.8) it can match anyone like i described, you should do dialplan organize correctly.

Comment: Please post your complete dialplan (not only trace) Thanks.