# Identify provider using Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, gsm, ivr

I want to set up an Asterisk and recognize from where the call is incoming, or which provider it is.

If it is a home phone line, redirect it to the IVR.

If it comes from cellphone line, redirect it to the corresponding GSM line, in order to reduce costs, since same provider phone call is free in my country.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! But it really depends on how the incoming call is being presented.

If its PSTN/POTS then you will need to ensure that your FXO card supports your regions caller ID system.

If its SIP or another IP based trunk then it will be included in the headers.

If you have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35440996/3788685) it will give you a basic idea of what you can do with matching patterns or complete caller ID's. Otherwise you can do all of what your thinking of in your question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Asterisk code, but I infer that in your code you detect the carrier by the firsts numbers of the caller ID. This won't work in my country (Argentina) since home lines and phone numbers are all mixed up, there's no way to tell by just looking at the number. Also there's a law that allows you to change your cellphone carrier and keep the exact same number, so it's just impossible to detect carrier using only the number.

Comment: Yes, my code looks at he inbound number then acts on it. I note your comments. How do *you* tell which carrier its from? we can prob make a lookup somehow. Are the inbound calls from landlines, mobiles, SIP or anything?

Comment: by lookup you mean use a third party service provider like twilio? Inbound calls can come either from landlines or mobiles.

Comment: yes presuming they have an api etc, but you need to at least tell us how you know where a call is coming from? I don't know if there is an online db or anything you can use specific to your location. Otherwise you could always build your own db of carriers based on your actual calls

Answer (score 0):

Every SIP trunk can have its own did. You can provide it in register statement. Also there is possiblity to assigne own context to every trunk.

More complicated solution is looking in SIP headers. This is only necessary when one trunk has many numbers/dids assigned.